# Can't access Facebook campaigns

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm unable to get a list of my campaigns using Facebook Graph API

Response for `/me/adaccounts`

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "account_id": "123456789000001234",
      "id": "act_123456789000001234"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "AAAAaaaBBBBcccc",
      "after": "AAAAaaaBBBBdddd"
    }
  }
}
```

`/123456789000001234/campaigns` returns

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '123456789000001234' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "EilRrOk1CEb"
  }
}
```

Note that id's have been changed to dummy-values.

The token is for a system user and the ad account have been assigned to the user (role: admin). Token contains following scopes: `read_page_mailboxes, rsvp_event, ads_management, ads_read, read_insights, manage_pages, publish_pages, pages_show_list, pages_manage_cta, pages_manage_instant_articles, business_management, publish_actions`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had to use `id: act_123456789000001234` instead of `account_id: 123456789000001234` so the request becomes `/act_123456789000001234/campaigns`. Also had to create a Facebook App, add Marketing API and assign to that an Ad Account, then create a token via the app instead of creating a token from the Business Manager.

Comment: Even using the npm module `facebook-ads-sdk` this was the case. Adding "act_" to the account ID fixed my problem!